# Pecl install when using multiple php.ini files

Tags: php, pear, pecl, php-ini

I'm installing APCu on my vagrant box, but found that pecl didn't have my ini files set on it, so I've added it manually & PHP in apache is now wokring fine, however my CLI uses a different php.ini file.  Is there an easy way to get installs to update both files at the same time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no out-of-the-box solution. pecl (which is `pear -c pecl.php.net`) only can update a single php.ini file.

What you could do is create one ini file and symlink it into the conf directories of each php version. (See "Scan for additional .ini files in" in `php --ini`).

Comment: Ah, that's a good idea.  Thanks for the suggestion.  Can I have multiple 'also scan this directory' directories set?  If so I could create a 'shared_inis' directory & get both configs to scan that, as well as their own specific ones.

Comment: No, you can have only one: `--with-config-file-scan-dir=PATH  Set the path where to scan for configuration files`

Answer (score 1):

I've recently learnt that you could use the following strategy:

```
echo "" > /etc/php5/mods-available/timezonedb.ini
pear config-set php_ini /etc/php5/mods-available/timezonedb.ini

pecl -q install -f timezonedb && php5enmod timezonedb
```

The `php5enmod` command will automatically link the configuration file to every SAPI (`cli`, `fpm`, ...).

### php5enmod

```
usage: php5enmod [ -s ALL|sapi_name ] module_name [ module_name_2 ]
```